# spring.codeconfig vs xml configuration

Tags: spring.net, spring.codeconfig

I've been using spring.net with xml configuration for some times, and I just saw that spring team released CodeConfig a month ago.

What I like about the xml config is that if I have a problem on the live server I can easily change the xml configuration to enable some specific debugging settings, or disable a specific component simply changing the xml configuration.

What is the advantage of using a code configuration instead of an xml configuration other than compile time check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With code config, possible benefits you could get are:

- Better refactoring support; e.g. renaming an injected property
- More compact configuration, compared to xml
- Developers can use *code*, in which they are often more at home than in xml

Benefit of the last point is also that developers new to the framework will have a significantly less steep learning curve than with the xml config.

From [the docs](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/introduction.html):

> While there are several positive
>   aspects to expressing configuration
>   metadata in XML files, there are also
>   many problems with this approach
>   including the verbosity of XML and its
>   heavy dependence on string-literals
>   which are both prone to typing errors
>   and unusually resistant to most modern
>   refactoring tools in use today. The
>   CodeConfig approach removes these
>   problems by providing a type safe,
>   code-based, approach to dependency
>   injection. It keeps the configuration
>   metadatda external to your class so
>   your class can be a POCO, free of any
>   DI related annotations.

Answer (score 2):

Just to highlight one thing, you can [mix and match configuration styles.](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/codeconfig-context.html#d4e363)  From within a CodeConfig class you can refere to XML config files using the [ImportResource] attribute (see [here](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/attribute-reference.html#importresource-attribute-reference)), and in the XML you can use the  namespace (see [here](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/sample-apps.html)).

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: thanks Mark. I cannot think of a use case when I would want to do that, but it's always good to know these things