# Spring.Net without configuring it in app.config

Tags: spring.net

Is there way to configure the objects from inside the code rather than configuring it in xml or app.config file.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064759/spring-codeconfig-vs-xml-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [spring.net homepage](http://www.springframework.net/), you'll find an announcement for the [CodeConfig](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/) project. CodeConfig allows you to create spring configuration from code, like for instance:

```cs
[Configuration]
public class MovieFinderConfiguration
{

    [Definition]
    public virtual MovieLister MyMovieLister()
    {
        MovieLister movieLister =  new MovieLister();
        movieLister.MovieFinder = FileBasedMovieFinder();
        return movieLister;

    }

    [Definition]
    public virtual IMovieFinder FileBasedMovieFinder()
    {
        return new ColonDelimitedMovieFinder(new FileInfo("movies.txt"));
    }
}
```

You can use this together with any xml configuration you might already have.