# Spring Framework basics

Tags: spring.net

I'm quite new to Spring Framework. Could someone please help me understand the spring configuration below?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

      <object type="Test.aspx">
        <property name="AService" ref="AService" />
        <property name="BService" ref="BService" />
      </object>
    </objects>
  </spring>
</configuration>
```

Basically questions in my mind are:
What does this line means:

```
<resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
```

and this:

```
<object type="Test.aspx">
            <property name="AService" ref="AService" />
            <property name="BService" ref="BService" />
          </object>
```

Does config: means configuration file?
Does ref means Classes in C#?

Comment: [Section 5](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html) of the [Spring.NET reference documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/index.html) does a fair job explaining what you see in the config.

Comment: If you are new to Spring.NET, perhaps you should switch to a faster and more modern framework.  Check out some benchmark tests at http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison .  I would suggest looking into StructureMap, Unity, or Windsor - all of which support in code configuration as opposed to Spring.NET forcing XML on you.

Comment: Hi Travis J, thank but application I am modifying is already written using Spring.NET. I dont' have any choice other than to understand above config.

Comment: @Travis - the blog post you are referencing *only* tests service locator style access of the ioc container. Spring.NET supports [configuration in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678409/spring-net-without-configuring-it-in-app-config/6679106#6679106).

Comment: @Marijn I've updated my question to be specific. I'm newbie to Spring.net. Treat me like L platter

Comment: @Marijn I see they finally got config in code. Service Locator is an anti pattern. In fact, resolving interfaces does *NOT* imply a service locator anti pattern. A DI container can be commonly misconstrued as a Service Locator, so it is not surprising that you came to such a conclusion. The benchmark tests register an interface, and then resolve it. This follows the Register Resolve Release pattern. The differences can be subtle. Asking to resolve a dependency graph is proper, whereas calling granular services from anywhere else is the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<resource uri="config://spring/objects" />` means that the spring container should read a configuration section from an [application configuration file (app.config or web.config)](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#d4e437).

`<object ...` is an object definition; this defines an object in your container. An object can have dependencies. In your case, the `Test.aspx` page has properties named `AService` and `BService`. The container will set these properties to the objects defined elsewhere in your container.

What might be a bit confusing here is the double usage of `="AService"` in `<property name="AService" ref="AService" />`:

- `name=`: refers to the name of the property on your class `Test`, there is a property defined as `public IMyService AService { get; set; }`
- `ref=` : refers to another object defined in your container, there is an object definition like `<object id="AService" type="MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" />` somewhere in your configuration.

The ["Instantiating the container"](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-instantiation) section of the spring docs does a good job of explaining this further.